# Json Deserialization on SSIS

Tags: json

I'm quite new to JSON and would like to ask your help.
I'm trying to deserialize Json into a object class but whenever I call JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize I get this error:

> Error: 0x1 at Data Flow Task, Error Getting Data From Webservice!:
>   System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined
>   for type of 'CurrencyOut[]'.    at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertDictionaryToObject(IDictionary`2
>   dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean
>   throwOnError, Object& convertedObject)

Here's the Json source:

```
{"terms":"http://www.xe.com/privacy.php","privacy":"http://www.xe.com/legal/dfs.php","to":"IDR","amount":100.0,"timestamp":"2015-06-01T16:00:00Z","from":[{"quotecurrency":"USD","mid":0.0075713171}]}
```

Here's my class:

```
class CurrencyOut
{
    public string Tems { get; set; }
    public string Privacy { get; set; }
    public CurrArr From { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string To { get; set; }

}

class CurrArr
{
    public string QuoteCurrency { get; set; }
    public decimal Mid { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks